# LDAP Auth on WAMP

Tags: php, windows, apache, ldap, wamp

I'm trying to write some LDAP authentication code on my WAMP server.

I'm using this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$ldapconfig['host'] = 'my.server.province.country';
$ldapconfig['port'] = 389;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'DC=x,DC=y,DC=z,DC=x1';
$ldapconfig['authrealm'] = 'My Realm';

ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']) or die ('Could not connect');

echo 'connected';
?>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function ldap_connect() in C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\oplweb\index.php
>   on line 10

From some basic Googling, it looks like I need to turn on mod_ldap. Seems simple. I've done the following:

- Went to C:\Program Files\Apache
  Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules
  and made sure that mod_ldap.so
  exists.
- I've gone into C:\Program
  Files\Apache Software
  Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf
  and made sure that this line is not
  commented out: LoadModule ldap_module
  modules/mod_ldap.so
- I've gone into
  C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini and made
  sure this line is not commented out:
  extension=php_ldap.dll
- Restart apache

The problem still persists. Does the ldap_connect() function in php have any other dependencies? Am I missing a step?

Cheers

Comment: Is your extension_dir set properly in your php.ini?

Comment: Also, unrelated to your problem, you're using $ldapconfig[] in one place and $ldap[] in another.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the issue with var names.

Comment: extension_dir ="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext" - that directory doesn't have php_ldap.dll that could be the issue.

Comment: Downloaded, added it in, still the same error.

Comment: I additionally had to modify the PATH environment variable like Slukehart mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue with my Windows Server 2008 - Have you added the php.ini file to your windows path?

---

Go to Control Panel and open the System icon (Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System, or just Start -> Control Panel -> System for Windows XP/2003+)

Go to the Advanced tab

Click on the 'Environment Variables' button

Look into the 'System Variables' pane

Find the Path entry (you may need to scroll to find it)

Double click on the Path entry

Enter your PHP directory at the end, including ';' before (e.g. ;C:\php)

Press OK

Comment: This and enabling LDAP in the proper PHP.ini file is what eventually allowed this work for me.

Comment: PHP in PATH and Enabling LDAP worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Check your phpinfo to make sure ldap is enabled.  You should see an LDAP section, and

Support | enabled

You may have php set to auto-enable anything in your extension dir, or you may have to manually enable it by uncommenting a line that looks like:

extension=php_ldap.dll

in your php.ini file

Remember to restart apache after you enable it.

Comment: There is not an LDAP section in the phpinfo. It does show up under apache2handler, in the loaded modules section.

Comment: Also, I've enabled it with extension=php_ldap.dll in the php.ini folder.

Comment: If you don't see it in your phpinfo output, then it is most likely not enabled.  I think that is your real problem.

Comment: I agree. But I've shown the steps I took to enable it, and no one seems to be able to spot a problem with how I went about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to an Active Directory, you can use this class which doesn't require any special PHP extension: http://sourceforge.net/projects/adldap/

Comment: This appears to require LDAP. It's example page returns an error stating that there's no support for LDAP in PHP.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't notice the LDAP extension was installed on the box I've been using.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently and I searched for `php.ini` on my disk and found that there are two `php.ini` files there -- one under the *php* directory and the other under the `apache\bin` directory. I uncommented the `extension=php_ldap.dll` line in both files and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

for WAMP, the working version of php.ini is located at apache\bin.
i was experienced same problem before until i change php.ini setting inside apache\bin and finally it works.

Comment: Just run phpinfo(), it will inform you where your php.ini is located